# Inserting HTML Form using CKeditor does not work

Tags: html, forms, paypal, ckeditor

I'm having a big issue using Ckeditor..
I want that my customer can add a paypal donation button trough a personnalised page.
When my customer want to add a customized page they use ckeditor.

To add a paypal button, they would have to  just copy / Paste the following code using the source mode:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="try@try.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Try">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_XC/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - la solution de paiement en ligne la plus simple et la plus sécurisée !">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_XC/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

However when they save the, somehow the html is modifyed with this one:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    &nbsp;</form>
```

I dont know how to avoid this.
I think it's an option in CKeditor config which is replacing some html codes but i'm not sure.

Thanks a lot for your futur advices,

Anselme

Comment: I've just tried pasting this HTML in editor on http://ckeditor.com/demo and getting data by getData() method. I haven't encountered any issue. Are you sure that you're using the latest CKEditor and doesn't have some non default settings?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is you've for a `form` in the editor, with a `form` in the content. You cannot have nested forms in HTML. You may have to come up with some tokenized tag-replacement  mechanism to get this to work.

I believe there is a form plug-in for ckeditor that may help.

Comment: No, that's not a problem if he codes the page properly. In CKEditor 3.x he just has to HTMLEncode the content of the textarea and such a problem doesn't happen.

Comment: CKEditor's content isn't nested in `form` - it's inside iframe, so it's separate scope.

Answer (score 0):

check the "Text format" below the ckeditor it should be "Full HTML"